# How to generate a midi file so that it can be interpreted by a light control board?

Tags: javascript, python, midi

I'm trying to send some RGB values to a light control board that has a MIDI input. The format of the information is not too relevant since i am the one generating the RGB values and I can just output them whichever way i want.

The issue I have is that i can't seem to find any documentation on how to convert non-musical data to MIDI. Does anyone have some info or idea on how to approach this?

Comment: Can you provide the brand/model/version of the light control board you are using ? Shame it doesn't have a simple "output green => input this" in the documentation...

Comment: Right, sorry, the model is MA2 Light and the brand is  MA Lingthing.

Comment: I don't know the device, but the manual says that you can configure MIDI Remotes, and that MIDI controllers can control faders.

Comment: You'll have to use an external hardware MIDI device to output from your computer, over a 5-pin DIN cable, and into the back of the MA2. The data you send needs to be actual MIDI messages (properly formatted, per spec) in order for the MA2 to interpret them -- this isn't just some trivial thing where the format "is not too relevant." I would suggest starting with the General MIDI specification, or perhaps a MIDI library in your favorite language.